# mysql cascade won't work when trying to update primary key that is referenced by 2 columns in a different table as foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem updating my database.

this is my structure:

I have 1 table that is named: 'users':

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)

INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('alice'),('bob'),('john');
```

And i have 1 table that is named: 'orders':

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `user1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `user2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user1`,`user2`),
  KEY `user2_idx` (`user2`),
  CONSTRAINT `user1` FOREIGN KEY (`user1`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `user2` FOREIGN KEY (`user2`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

INSERT INTO `orders` VALUES ('alice','bob',NULL),('alice','john',NULL),('bob','bob',NULL);
```

This means that an order consists of 2 users, that is a record of 'orders' table is combined from 2 foreign keys referencing the 'users' table.

the problem i am experiencing is that i now need to change the username of a user.

as the code above specifies i have:
3 users: 'alice','bob' and 'john'
3 orders: ('alice','bob'), ('alice','john'), ('bob','bob')

if i try to edit 'alice' or 'john' usernames then the operation will succeed and the cascade will change all orders accordingly.

but if i try to change 'bob' username to something else i will get this horrible error message which i just can't figure why:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
UPDATE `test`.`users` SET `username`='bobd' WHERE `username`='bob';

ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `user2` FOREIGN KEY (`user2`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `test`.`users` SET `username`='bobd' WHERE `username`='bob'
```

Comment: You should never update a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon this clause has bitten you in the butt:

[Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> Between two tables, do not define several `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clauses that act on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.

As you can see, the server issues a separate `UPDATE` statement for each constraint for the cascade update. But, if there are two columns affected, neither of the statements can produce a valid row on its own!

A possible solution here is to use user IDs as their unique identities that never change rather that any secondary information.
In fact, this is a time-proven best practice in cases where anything can change with time: [Do natural keys provide higher or lower performance in SQL Server than surrogate integer keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50708/do-natural-keys-provide-higher-or-lower-performance-in-sql-server-than-surrogate?lq=1) outlines the pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

Your entry of bob,bob is the problem as it has two keys(primary, foreign key) and two constraints(user1, user2) associated with it. All of them reference the same field, users.username.  This seriously confuses the database software and is bad design.

Simplest solution is to drop the constraints, update the tables and re-establish the constraints.

In your users table you should use an ID, Name with the key on ID.  Then in the orders table, use ID,ID.  Then you can update names in one table without a problem.

To help with database design, you should read up on third-normal-form.

Comment: A "drop the constraints, update the tables and re-establish the constraints"-type solution is a big no-no anywhere near production (specifically, when there's any possibility the database is in use).

Comment: i am in serious production

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when using JPA/Hibernate.  The DDL update (hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update) created duplicate foreign key constraints.  I removed the my original constraints, and left the generated ones. That fixed my issues.